# Merge strategy for whitespace only changes?

Tags: git, code-formatting, git-merge

I did a code format in master branch. It mainly fixed whitespace issues like: formatting tab space lengths, adds and removes newlines before and after braces. The problem is, when I try to merge master from other branches I get a lot of conflicts. Is there some strategy to bring in whitespace changes to other branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of [`git merge`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-merge.html), I would assume that

```
git merge -s recursive -Xignore-space-change
```

could be used to achieve this. You might also want to play around with

- `-Xignore-all-space` or
- `-Xignore-space-at-eol`

Comment: This helped a lot. However, conflicts still ocurred. It was much easier to resolve them when I did code format in both branches first and then merged them with the above method.

Comment: For those who are wondering why this solution doesn't work, it was not introduced until 1.7.4 https://raw.github.com/gitster/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.4.txt